# Number of multiples of 2 or 3 in range [1,100]

Tags: elementary-number-theory, solution-verification

I am reading the problem:

> How many numbers between $[1, 100]$ are multiples of $2$ or multiples
> of $3$? (Caution to avoid double counting)

My approach:
Numbers that are multiple of $2$
$2, 4, 6, 8, ....100$
$1, 2, 3, 4, ....\frac{100}{2}=50$

Hence $50$ multiples of $2$

Numbers that are multiple of $3$
$3, 6, 9, 12, ....99$
$1, 2, 3, 4, ....\frac{99}{3}=33$

Hence $33$ multiples of $3$. But these double count the multiples of $2$ when the number is a multiple of $6$.

Numbers that are multiple of $6$:
$6, 12, 18, 24, ....96$
$1, 2, 3, 4, ....\frac{96}{6}=16$

So the answer to the original question is:
$50 + 33 - 16 = 67$

Is there something in the logic that could be improved or be more efficient? Am I over complicating something?

Comment: That *is* the way to do it.  There are $50$ multiples of $2$ and $33$ multiples of $3$ but $16$ are multiples of both.  You *could* figure in any group of $6$ integer from $6k+1,...., 6(k+1)$ that $6k+2, 6k+3, 6k+5, 6(k+1)$ are multiples of $2$ or $3$ and $6k+1$ and $6k+5$ are not.  So $\frac 46=\frac 23$  of the numbers from $1... 96$ so $\frac 23\times 96 = 64$.  Then include $98,99$ and $100$ for $67$ but I would think that was any more efficient.

Comment: This is correct, and the most elegant approach in my opinion.  Another way to do it is to notice that a number $k$ is divisible by 2 or 3 iff $k \nequiv \pm 1 \bmod 6$  So, if  $6|n$,  The number of multiples of 2 or 3 in [1,n] is $4*(\frac n 6)$  So the number of multiples of 2 or 3 in [1,96] is $4*16=64$.  Then we have to consider 97,98,99, and 100 by hand, 3 of which are multiples of 2 or 3.  So the answer is 64+3=67

Comment: Cf. [inclusion-exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: Hi, I know it's a bit of a late comment, but the website recommended me this post. One way you could slightly improve your reasoning is to justify why $6$. In fact it comes from the fact that $2$ and $3$ do not share any common divisors other than $1$, so any multiple of both is a multiple of their product. More generally, you can say that any number that is a multiple of $x$ and $y$ is a multiple of their lowest common multiple, which might be different than their product.

Answer (score 1):

No, your logic is perfect in this case. The only way I can think of to perhaps make it a little more refined is this: to count the number of multiples of $2$, or $3$ or $6$, you can observe that the sequences form arithmetic progressions, whose $n^{th}$ term is given by:
$$a_n=a_1+(n-1)d$$
So, for example, number of multiples of $6$ would be:
$$96=6+(n-1)6$$
So $n=16$, hence $16$ multiples of $6$.

Perhaps this could shave off a few seconds from your solution, for intervals more complex than $[1,100]$, such as, say, $[23,567]$, in which case you wouldn't get a simple ratio between the term and the order of the term.

Comment: In general, non-initial intervals like $[23,567]$ can be handled by writing it as the difference between $[1,567]$ and $[1,22]$.